# java-getting a numeric database value

Tags: java, sql, database

Hello I am working on a java code that is suppose to get the count of the total number of users in  the user profile table I am working on. Now I am sure I got the sql statement right but for some reason I dont know how to get the numeric value from it. Any help is greatly appreciated and welcomed.I am sure the way I am trying to get the value doesn't work but I dont know how to get the value, Here is the code below and thank you:

```
     public int getUserCount() throws SQLException {    

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    double encinfo;
    conn = DAOFactory.getDatabaseDAO().getConnection();
        StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
        query.append( "Select COUNT (DISTINCT record_id)");
        query.append( "From USER_PROFILE");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery( query.toString());
        if (!rs.next())
           throw new SQLException( SQLException.User_NOT_FOUND,"No User Count found.");

        // Should be able to get the user amount or value or total users in DB.
        userInfo = rs.getDouble( "USER_VALUE");

        m_userCount = (int) userInfo;
   }
```

Comment: You may also want to put a space between the count() and from so it can properly parse the sql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may work:

Add alias to record count:

```
  query.append( "Select COUNT (DISTINCT record_id) AS USER_VALUE");
        query.append( " From USER_PROFILE");
```

Another way could be:

```
rs.getDouble(1);
```

Here 1 is the index of column.

Answer (score 3):

```
rs.getDouble(1);
```

Since you have 1 column, it will return the value of the current row and 1st column